# How can I set a height to a Dialog in Material-UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm going with the Material-UI example for a `Dialog` with a custom width:

```
const customContentStyle = {
  width: '100%',
  maxWidth: 'none',
};

// some omitted code

<Dialog
  title="Dialog With Custom Width"
  actions={actions}
  modal={true}
  contentStyle={customContentStyle}
  open={this.state.open}
>
  This dialog spans the entire width of the screen.
</Dialog>
```

I know that I'm able to set a custom width because I've overridden the `maxWidth`, however I want to be able to do the same with the height so that I can resize the height of the dialog. I've tried setting the `maxHeight` to `none` and setting `height`, but I've had no luck with it.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You need to [override some of the default behavior](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/overrides/#overriding-with-classes) of the [Dialog](https://material-ui-next.com/api/dialog/).  Its `paper` class implements a flexbox with a columnar flex-direction and defines a max-height of `90vh`.  This allows the Dialog to grow to its content and present scrollbars once it reaches 90% of the viewport's visible height.

If you need to set the Dialog height to some percentage of the viewport, override the `paper` class, defining `min-height` and `max-height` in a manner similar to the example below:

```js
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import Dialog from 'material-ui/Dialog';

const styles = {
    dialogPaper: {
        minHeight: '80vh',
        maxHeight: '80vh',
    },
};

const YourDialog = ({ classes }) => (
    <Dialog classes={{ paper: classes.dialogPaper }}>
        <div>dialogishness</div>
    </Dialog>
);

export default withStyles(styles)(YourDialog);
```

This will ensure that the Dialog's height is 80% of the viewport.

Comment: Is there an inline way to do this?  This creates a new Dialog component but what if I want just one single dialog to be slightly different?

Comment: You can override the paper class wherever Dialog is used.  You don’t have to create a new component.  In the example, just pretend YourDialog is a component that implements a Dialog.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't get it working that way.  In the end I wrapped content in a div and applied styles to that eg. padding, min-width.  I'm still on a learning curve with material-ui so that's probably not correct way to do it ... but in case anyone else is having challenges it's a way.

Comment: I added classes=xxx to the <Dialog.../> I already had, worked great.

Answer (score 33):

In **MUI v5**, you can override the `max-height` value of the inner `Paper` component by using this code:

```
<Dialog
  PaperProps={{
    sx: {
      width: "50%",
      maxHeight: 300
    }
  }}
  {...other}
>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 47698037/how-can-i-set-a-height-to-a-dialog-in-material-ui]

Answer (score 20):

Set the height of the DialogContent child instead. The dialog will grow to contain its contents. You can do this with css / classname, etc... but to do it inline, here is a code-snippet:

```
<Dialog
        open={open}
        fullWidth
        maxWidth='lg' // set width according to defined material ui breakpoints
        onClose={handleClose}
>
        <DialogContent
        style={{height:'600px'}}> // set height by pixels, percentage, etc
            //insert content here
        </DialogContent>
</Dialog>
```

Comment: Thanks, nice and simple.

Answer (score 7):

Some of the answers seem so overly complex, here's a quick and clean in-line method that works for MUI v4 and possibly for v5 too:

```
<Dialog
  open={true}
  onClose={onClose}
  ... and other props
  PaperProps={{ style: {
    minHeight: '90%',
    maxHeight: '90%',
  }}}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a newer version of material-ui use this:

```
import MuiDialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';

const Dialog = withStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    height: '100%' // 100% is for full height or anything else what you need
  },
}))(MuiDialog);

export default function SomeComponentThatUsesCustomizedDialog() {
    return (
        <Dialog>
        ...
        </Dialog>
    )
}
```

The `dialogPaper` prop used in the accepted answer doesn't work for me and throws an error in the console (we're using material-ui v.4.11+, where it's not even listed in the [official dialog css api docs](https://material-ui.com/api/dialog/#css)). Hence, use the `paper` prop instead.

Inspired by [official example](https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs/#customized-dialogs).