# React MUI: Set fixed height for Dialog component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to create a dialog (https://mui.com/components/dialogs/), I have tried setting the sx value minHeight, height etc. but when the dialog renders it changes height depending on whats inside.

How can I fix the height to 80% of the window and make sure it does not shrink when there is less content to fill the space?

```
<Dialog onClose={handleClose} open={open} fullWidth={true} maxWidth="lg" sx={{ height: '80%' }}>
        <DialogTitle sx={{ m: 0, p: 2 }}>
            Search drft
            <IconButton
            aria-label="close"
            onClick={handleClose}
            sx={{
                position: 'absolute',
                right: 8,
                top: 8,
                color: (theme) => theme.palette.grey[500],
            }}
            >
                <CloseIcon />
            </IconButton>
        </DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent dividers>
        {/* <DialogTitle>Search drft</DialogTitle> */}
            <GlobalSearch />
        </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
```

Update: following some advice from a different question I made the following update and the dialog is now fixed at 80% height no matter how tall the content is!

```
<Dialog
  PaperProps={{
    sx: {
      minHeight: '80%',
      maxHeight: '80%'
    }
  }}
  {...other}
>
```

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47763027/8924525) your question?

Comment: @Vektor the accepted answer did not but the one below it (MUI v5 specific did), I set minHeight and maxHeight to '100%' and its now not jumping heights based on the content - thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: That's great! You should place the solution in an answer, then accept it.

Comment: add `overflow:'auto'` to your Dialog `sx` props. that way if more content gets in, then paper will stay at 80% but internal scrollbar will appear and content can be scrollable.